# How do I pull rows with non-null values in a field in FuelSDK?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, fuel-sdk, python

I'm using the Python FuelSDK, and I want to pull all rows of a DE where a specific field is not null.

I've tried both of these for the search_filter:

```
{'Property': 'FieldName', 'SimpleOperator': 'notEquals', 'Value': None}
{'Property': 'FieldName', 'SimpleOperator': 'notEquals', 'Value': ''}
```

When I use `None` I get this error:

`Error: Invalid argument for the notEquals operator. Filter array cannot be null.`

When I use `''` I get:

`Error: Invalid argument for the notEquals operator. Filter[0] cannot be null or empty.`

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Python FuelSDK, but have you tried the name/value pair `'Value': null` ?

Comment: None is the python equivalent of Null.  `'Value': Null` throws an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unfamiliar with the Python Fuel SDK, so my first suggestion could be completely dumb due to my ignorance.

Can you use the simpleoperator "[isNotNull](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/simpleoperators/)" equivalent in python (if it exists)?

This next answer is not exactly the most elegant solution, but you could try:

1 Pull the rows (without filters)

2 Take a rowcount of the data and start a for loop

3 For loop should be something like: (using ampscript as example)

```
FOR @i = 1 TO @rowcount  DO 
   SET @row = Row(@yourdata,@i)        
   SET @length = length(field(@row,'Fieldname'))

   IF @length > 0 THEN
       ADD to a new object/array or DE, whichever you prefer
   ENDIF

NEXT @i
```

*Another option to use instead of Length() is to use the IsNull() or EMPTY() function instead.*

4 Use the new DE or object/array for your need.

This will definitely add time to your scripts, so on a large file it will not work - but as I do not see a simple alternative via the filter function I thought I should share.

A final option, very much duct tape and gum, is to build a filter activity that uses the argument "Fieldname is empty" and call that activity as your filter.  The issue is that it will only work on a single Data Extension and cannot be used universally or on non-data extensions.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pulling all rows now and doing the filtering in python, but scale is becoming an issue. There's at least a dozen DEs I need to pull nightly, and being able to have a not null filter would speed it up immensely. 

The good news is, 'isNotNull' seems to work. Thanks for linking that page with the other SimpleOperator functions. That's super useful, and I hadn't seen it before.

Comment: Glad to hear I could help even a little bit. Yeah, there are a lot of cool reference pages available, but unfortunately SFMC is not very good at making these pages searchable or easy to find/naviage to for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI if anyone ends up here: was being bothered by `isNull` / `isNotNull` filters in a Script Activity for a while and just found out that you can make it work this way:

```js
var filter = {
  Property: 'Status',
  SimpleOperator: 'isNull',
  Value: ''
}
```

The key is leaving the `Value: ''` in the filter object as there'll be an error otherwise.

Comment: Thank you - I searched the entire internet for this answer!