# Filter a data extension in SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I am trying to filter a data extension to only return certain rows via an SSJS automation.

It works fine if I set the SimpleOperator to "equals" and the Value to a static value.

What I really want to be able to do is filter rows with NULL in a particular field. I tried "notEquals" but it doesn't seem to work. e.g.

```
// FILTER ROWS THAT DON'T HAVE A STATUS OF PROCESSED
var TARGET_DE = DataExtension.Init("7AAB4709-88A6-4C4E-B153-901351D820A1");
var Filter = {Property:"Status",SimpleOperator:"notEquals",Value:"processed"};
var Data = TARGET_DE.Rows.Retrieve(Filter);
```

(Note: If the value isn't processed it is NULL)

I suspect I'm not able to use the SimpleOperator filter for NULL values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use the [simple operator of isNull](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/simpleoperators.htm) to achieve this.

> You can use operators when building filters. The operators below work
>   for all objects:
>
> - equals
> - notEquals
> - greaterThan
> - lessThan
> - isNull
> - isNotNull
> - greaterThanOrEqual
> - lessThanOrEqual
> - between
> - IN
> - like

If not, then you could try:

```
var Filter = {Property:"Status",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:""};
```

This should make the value default to NULL and SHOULD only pull records accordingly. (Have not tested)

Your notEquals statement is requiring a value (which does not include NULL or EMPTY) that is not the declared value.

There are also a couple other not as elegant solutions you could look for. See this answer for some examples: [How do I pull rows with non-null values in a field in FuelSDK?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141153/how-do-i-pull-rows-with-non-null-values-in-a-field-in-fuelsdk)

Comment: I managed to get this working. Based on your suggestion I used:

`var Filter = {Property:"Status",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:" "};`

However to get it to work I had to use a space in the value like " "

Also in this documentation based on the SDK null filters aren't an option but I'm not sure if it applies. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-sdks.meta/mc-sdks/data-extension-row-retrieve.htm

Comment: You can use `var filter = {Property:"Field name",SimpleOperator:"isNull"};
`